# Can't create SQL table - Error 1005 defined

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not being allowed to create the following table. Is it because of the compound primary key? I have added the information for the users and titles table as well, in case there is a problem in the code there.

```
CREATE TABLE store
(
    short_name  VARCHAR(5)                      NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    address1    VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
    address2    VARCHAR(20),
    city        VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    state       VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    zip         VARCHAR(10)                     NOT NULL,
    phone       VARCHAR(15)                     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT store_pk PRIMARY KEY (short_name)
);

CREATE TABLE publishers
(
    name        VARCHAR(50)                         NOT NULL,
    status      TINYINT         DEFAULT 1           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT publishers_pk PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id          INT                     NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name        VARCHAR(70)                     NOT NULL,
    password    VARCHAR(60),        
    address1    VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
    address2    VARCHAR(20),
    city        VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    state       VARCHAR(30)                     NOT NULL,
    zip         VARCHAR(10)                     NOT NULL,
    phone       VARCHAR(15),
    email       VARCHAR(90),
    store       VARCHAR(5),
    admin       TINYINT             DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL,
    mail_list   TINYINT             DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL,
    active      TINYINT             DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT users_fk FOREIGN KEY (store)
        REFERENCES store (short_name)
        ON DELETE   SET NULL
        ON UPDATE   CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE titles
(
    id          INT                 NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    publisher   VARCHAR(50),
    title       VARCHAR(50)         NOT NULL,
    status      ENUM('active', 'announced', 'inactive'),
    discount    TINYINT             NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT title_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT title_fk FOREIGN KEY (publisher)
        REFERENCES publishers (name)
        ON DELETE   SET NULL
        ON UPDATE   CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE subscriptions
(
    user        INT,
    title       INT,
    quantity    TINYINT             DEFAULT 1           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT subscription_pk PRIMARY KEY (user, title),
    CONSTRAINT subscription_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (user)
        REFERENCES users (id)
        ON DELETE   SET NULL
        ON UPDATE   CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT subscription_title_fk FOREIGN KEY (title)
        REFERENCES titles (id)
        ON DELETE   SET NULL
        ON UPDATE   CASCADE
);
```

Comment: give detail of `users` & `titles` tables

Comment: You can get more information about the error by typing `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` usually.

Comment: I have updated the information with the other tables.

Comment: Have you already created the `store` and `publishers` tables?

Comment: Yes the other tables have been created.

Comment: With `name` and `short_name` as *indexed* columns?  Can you update the question with the table definitions for store and publishers?

Comment: Yes they are both primary keys.

Comment: I have added the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the table definitions, only the `subscriptions` table gave a problem, and that's because of the `ON DELETE SET NULL` clause.  Both `user` and `title` columns in the `subscriptions` table are defined as `NOT NULL`!

Comment: @JimRomeFan try this SQL Fiddle. It's your DDL with the `ON DELETE SET NULL` removed, and it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dedec

Comment: OK, I see what I had to do. I had to remove the ON DELETE SET NULL clause. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The primay keys are defined wrong. `constraint title_pk primary key (id)` and those alike are wrong. they should be like `primary key(id)`

Comment: Huh? Are you talking about the space between the parentheses? That is not the error.

Comment: no im talking about removing the words like `constraint title_pk`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably failing on the foreign key constraints.

Run this:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

And look at the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section. That should tell you the problem.

If the users and/or titles tables don't exist yet, you should run this before creating your tables:

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

If those tables do exist, it's possible that the data types don't match between the parent columns (i.e. user.id) and the child columns (i.e. user).

Comment: How do I run the \G command? I'm using mysql workbench or phpmyadmin.

Comment: @JimRomeFan The `\G` is specific to the mysql client. It tells the client to display the results vertically. In your client you can skip that: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`

Comment: It didn't produce anything. I exported the results and it was blank.